# List of contacts for User

Tags: django

I have a `UserProfile` model, which extends User model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='0')
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    key_expires = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
```

I want to make every user to have a list of contacts. Contact is an object of `User` model. I want to make list of contacts like in Skype or social network.
I have tried to make in like this:

```
class UserContact(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='contacts')
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
```

But I think that something is wrong. Because if I select everything from `UserContact` model, I receive the whole list of usernames, without ID's of users from `User` model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should checkout [`Many-To-Many` relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField).

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='0')
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    key_expires = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Comment: In this case I have a data like this: `{'id': '5', 'username': 'someuser', ..., 'avatar': 'someavatar' , 'contacts': {'id': '5', 'username':'someuser', ...} }`. It's a redundancy or not? Is there any way to include only `username` field in this ManyToMany relationship?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What is good? And define what you expect from "being good".

Comment: If we use Many-to-many relationship, every user have every field of `User` model in `contacts` field. I want to make it so that in this relationship user have only `username` field.

Comment: Why would you want only `username` field? If, for one specific query, you only need usernames, then just do `my_user.contacts.all().only('username')` to avoid selecting extra columns.